# ros2 how to get non-ros parameter argument count

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have code like:

```
int main(...)
{
   rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

   if(argc != 3) {
      printf("Error, missing arguments for a, b\n");
 }
...
```

The problem with this is that when using launch_testing.launch_test, or any launch file and specifying arguments for my application, these tools/libraries are adding extra parameters like:

```
mcu_sim_test 20 -50 --ros-args -r __node:=test -r __ns:=/mcu_sim_namespace
```

These additional --ros-args are throwing off the argument counts even though they aren't being used by my package but rather used by ros2.

I did see that this is an intentional change from ros1 where the argc/argv were being altered and that makes a ton of sense. Where I'm stuck is how to address it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348825/ros2-how-to-get-non-ros-parameter-argument-count/) by [cmorgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/52818/cmorgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For rclcpp, in `#include <utilities.hpp>` you have the following two functions that return a std::vectorstd::string with the argv trimmed down of any ROS arguments:

```
std::vector<std::string>
init_and_remove_ros_arguments(
  int argc,
  char const * const * argv,
  const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
```

and:

```
std::vector<std::string>
remove_ros_arguments(int argc, char const * const * argv);
```

---

In python rclpy, you have `args = rclpy.utilities.remove_ros_args(sys.argv)` which does the same thing.

---

Originally posted by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) with karma: 280 on 2022-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) on 2022-02-10**:
I know this is a reply to a 2yo question, but it's worthy of an answer. :)